# jQuery JSONP "has no method 'json'" parse error

Tags: jquery, jsonp

I am attempting to make a jsonp call with jQuery 1.7 but when the call returns I get the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object function ( response ) {
>             responseContainer = [ response ];       } has no method 'json'

When inspecting the data being returned I noticed that '.json' is being appended to the callback function name:

```
jQuery17206211688306648284_1336426518269.json({"..."})
```

Here is the code that is making the request:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "...",
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  success: function(data) {
    return console.log(data);
  }
});
```

**Answer:**

As **adeneo** said the server was trying to specify a callback function of 'json' this is handled by setting the following parameter on the $.ajax call:

```
jsonpCallback: 'json'
```

Comment: Then it would seem that your server is adding `.json` to the function name provided by jQuery. Therefore, when the script runs, the `jQuery17206211688306648284_1336426518269` function is found, and it tries to look up a `.json` property on the function object, and invoke it as if it was a method of the object.

Comment: Try this. Add `jsonpCallback: 'foo'` to your request, and create an object in global scope. `window.foo = { json: function(data) { console.log(data);} };` I'm betting the server will return `foo.json({"..."})`, invoking the object/method you created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery's $.ajax function automagically adds a callback function to jsonp requests, but it looks like the `json()` function you are seeing is added by the server, but you could try :

```
$.ajax({
  url: "...",
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  jsonp: false,
  success: function(data) {
    return console.log(data);
  }
});
```

To disable the jQuery auto callback thingy, or just create an empty chainable function with the name `json()`

Comment: I guess I don't understand where the .json is being appended.  This is a request being made from client side javascript so it shouldn't be routed through my server at all.  The remote url is from a third-party and I'ved tried it different apis all appending the .json

Comment: Yes, it's not your server per se, but the server that sends back the jsonp result that has a callback function named `json()`, if i remember correctly this site (SO) has something similar, where the callback name also is specified in the returned result, for sites that does not specify a callback function, jQuery built in magic is useful.

Comment: Your were correct the server was trying to specify a callback name of 'json'.  I was able to fix it by setting: jsonpCallback: 'json'.  Thank You!